# Merging two or more dictionaries when they have the same key value pairs

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to merge two or more dictionaries in a list to combine them using same set of key value pairs. If the specified key value pairs exists, then merge the other keys for those dictionaries gets added under 'other_cols'. Below is what my input looks like and what I am expecting as an output.

```
input_list = [{'a': 1, 'b' : 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4},
              {'a': 1, 'b' : 2, 'c': 5, 'd': 6},
              {'a': 9, 'b' : 10, 'c': 11, 'd': 12},
              {'a': 9, 'b' : 10, 'c': 13, 'd': 14},
              {'a': 9, 'b' : 10, 'c': 15, 'd': 16},
              {'a': 17, 'b' : 18, 'c': 19, 'd': 20},
              {'a': 1, 'b' : 2, 'c': 7, 'd': 8}]

merge_by_keys = ['a','b']

expected_output_list = [{'a': 1, 'b' : 2, 'other_cols':[{'c': 3, 'd': 4},
                                                        {'c': 5, 'd': 6},
                                                        {'c': 7, 'd': 8}],
                        {'a': 9, 'b' : 10, 'other_cols':[{'c': 11, 'd': 12},
                                                         {'c': 13, 'd': 14},
                                                         {'c': 15, 'd': 16}],
                        {'a': 17, 'b' : 18, 'other_cols':[{'c': 19, 'd': 20}]}
```

Comment: Do not overwrite built-in functions - e.g., input, zip, dict, list, etc.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's customary to attempt writing some code, then ask when you get stuck. Do you have some code to share? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's one way to do it using a dictionary to group entries and turning its values into a list at the end.

```
input_list = [{'a': 1, 'b' : 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4},
              {'a': 1, 'b' : 2, 'c': 5, 'd': 6},
              {'a': 9, 'b' : 10, 'c': 11, 'd': 12},
              {'a': 9, 'b' : 10, 'c': 13, 'd': 14},
              {'a': 9, 'b' : 10, 'c': 15, 'd': 16},
              {'a': 17, 'b' : 18, 'c': 19, 'd': 20},
              {'a': 1, 'b' : 2, 'c': 7, 'd': 8}]

merge_keys = ['a','b']

grouped = dict()
for d in input_list:
    groupKey  = tuple(map(d.get,merge_keys))
    groupDict = grouped.setdefault(groupKey,{k:d.pop(k) for k in merge_keys})
    groupDict.setdefault('other_cols',[]).append(d)
result = list(grouped.values())

print(result)
[{'a': 1,  'b': 2,  'other_cols': [{'c': 3, 'd': 4},
                                   {'c': 5, 'd': 6},
                                   {'c': 7, 'd': 8}]},
 {'a': 9,  'b': 10, 'other_cols': [{'c': 11, 'd': 12},
                                   {'c': 13, 'd': 14},
                                   {'c': 15, 'd': 16}]},
 {'a': 17, 'b': 18, 'other_cols': [{'c': 19, 'd': 20}]}]
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot Alain. This code looks pretty simple and easy to understand and works perfectly. Thumb's Up!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like what you are looking for:

The most interesting line is:

`out[tuple((entry[x],x) for x in merge_by_keys)].append({k: v for k, v in entry.items() if k not in merge_by_keys})`

Make sure you understand it. Ask if you have questions.

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4},
        {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 5, 'd': 6},
        {'a': 9, 'b': 10, 'c': 11, 'd': 12},
        {'a': 9, 'b': 10, 'c': 13, 'd': 14},
        {'a': 9, 'b': 10, 'c': 15, 'd': 16},
        {'a': 17, 'b': 18, 'c': 19, 'd': 20},
        {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 7, 'd': 8}]

merge_by_keys = ['a', 'b']
out = defaultdict(list)
for entry in data:
    out[tuple((entry[x],x) for x in merge_by_keys)].append({k: v for k, v in entry.items() if k not in merge_by_keys})


result = []
for k, v in out.items():
    result.append({})
    for x in k:
        result[-1][x[1]] = x[0]
    result[-1]['other'] = v
for entry in result:
    print(entry)
```

output

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'other': [{'c': 3, 'd': 4}, {'c': 5, 'd': 6}, {'c': 7, 'd': 8}]}
{'a': 9, 'b': 10, 'other': [{'c': 11, 'd': 12}, {'c': 13, 'd': 14}, {'c': 15, 'd': 16}]}
{'a': 17, 'b': 18, 'other': [{'c': 19, 'd': 20}]}
```

Comment: Woah! It worked like a charm. Thanks a lot for your help. I kept thinking for days around this but you cracked it open in minutes. I think I do understand what you did while adding items in the defaultdict. But I kind of lost you in the second loop. But I will get the very core of it. Thanks again for all your help. A big shoutout to you!

Comment: I have a question about that long line. I don't understand why you use `(entry[x],x)` instead of `(x,entry[x])`. Since the latter allows `result.append(dict(k))` :-)